# Null Reference Exception while Iterating over a List<T>

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I'm getting a null exception while iterating over a collection of non nullable objects.

```
List<ReconFact> facts = new List<ReconFact>();
// ...populating facts 

int count = 0;

foreach (var fact in facts)
{
  Console.WriteLine(++count);
  try
  {
    context = AddToContext(context, fact, count, 100, true);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // Null Exception Raised at some point
  }
}
```

How is that possible ? I didn't know that iterating over a list could provide null elements is that a normal behaviour ? Is it possible to add a null item when the list is populated ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx, Yes and Yes

Comment: What are you doing inside AddToContext() function?

Comment: You should find out where the Exception gets thrown, then you might see the problem, not where its get caught. Maybe it isn't a null ReconFact reference but something in ReconFact is null?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's  possible to add `null` to a `List<T>` where `T` is a reference type. Nothing prevents someone from:

```
List<ReconFact> facts = new List<ReconFact>();
facts.Add(null);
```

You could simply check that first:

```
foreach (var fact in facts.Where(f => f != null))
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a `List` can contain nulls, so can arrays and several other collections.
It won't break the iterating itself, but it will break any code inside the `{ }` that relies on the element not being null.

```
List<String> s = new List<String>();
s.Add("foo");
s.Add(null);
s.Add("bar");
```

**Edit:** Wait, what do you mean by "non-nullable objects"?

Comment: By non nullable objects I mean object that are not of the type `Nullable<Type>`

Comment: But are they structs or classes? Classes are reference types, so they can be null even if not `Nullable<type>`. In fact, the compiler will reject any try to `Nullable` a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your logic. You just initialize the list of Recontent named `fact`.
So all time its count is 0. Please check that.